# AngularJs ng-click fire twice only on button tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code:

```
<button class="button large" type="button"
      ng-click="vm.submitWithoutPreview(listingForm)">Next
</button>
```

I dont know why, this fire twice the submitWithoutPreview() function, but i change it to:

```
<a href="#" class="button large"
      ng-click="vm.submitWithoutPreview(listingForm)">Next
</a>
```

this doesnt fire twice. Any reason why? i really dont want to change all the buttons to an 'a' tag.

EDIT:

The controller is like this:

```
export class AppController {
  submit(listingForm) {
    console.log("Fire from submit");
  }

  submitWithoutPreview(listingForm) {
    console.log("Fire");
  }
}
```

Then on a module:

```
import {AppController} from './app.controller';
const appModule = angular.module('app.module1', [])
.controller('AppController', AppController)
```

Everything is working right now but i dont know why only the ng-click on a button fired twice and in the a tag works fine, its pretty complicated for me to add a fiddle with all the code

Comment: Are you sure, you don't have an `onClick` listener else where for the button? Add a fiddle which reproduces this issue.

Comment: Not possible. The given code is fine. Please add your controller code also.

Comment: I just add the controller's code

Comment: just to clarify, by fire twice, did you mean the submitWithoutPreview() is called twice when you actually clicked once?

Comment: Yeah! i clicked once and got 2 console.log and still dont know why